# How to get a value from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables "srot_data" and "vada"

```
CREATE TABLE `srot_data` (`ID` int(10) NOT NULL,Datum` datetime DEFAULT NULL,`ID_obsluha` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,`Linka` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,`Kontejner` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,`Vada` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,`m_srot` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,`m_pres` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,`blok` int(10) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `vada` (`ID` int(10) NOT NULL,`Cislo` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,`Popis` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `srot_data` (`ID`, `Datum`, `ID_obsluha`, `Linka`, `Kontejner`, `Vada`, `m_srot`, `m_pres`, `blok`) VALUES(1, '2018-04-16 11:23:44', 21, 'EXMET2', 'ELDY-', 18, '27.500', '12.500', 1),
INSERT INTO `vada` (`ID`, `Cislo`, `Popis`) VALUES(1, 1, 'Najíždění výroby(resp. nové elektrody)'),(2, 2, 'Expander - poškozená mřížka'),(3, 3, 'Olověný pás - koroze '),(4, 4, 'Olověný pás - potrhaná mřížka'),(5, 5, 'Pastovačka - nedopastované elektrody'),(6, 6, 'Pastovačka - nerovnoměrné pastování (křivé stohy)'),
```

I need to get:

```
  {"Total":"37", "vada":"Pastovačka - nedopastované elektrody".}
```

But this is what I get now

```
{"Total":"37", "vada":"5".}
```

My sql is:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(blok) AS Total , 
           Vada AS vada 
    FROM srot_data 
    LEFT JOIN vada ON vada.Popis = srot_data.Vada 
    WHERE Linka = 'EXMET1' 
    GROUP BY vada 
    ORDER BY Total DESC limit 1";
```

"vada": "Pastovačka - nedopastované elektrody" is Popis from table vada, which has number 5 in table srot_data.

How do I get the value instead of number?

Comment: i doubt you get JSON data from that query.. I assume your JSON generation code is within your application layer (PHP)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should select `Popis` column.
2. And Your Join column is wrong as you say. It should be `LEFT JOIN vada ON vada.Vada = srot_data.Vada`

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT count(blok) AS Total ,   
          Popis AS vada   
          FROM srot_data   
          LEFT JOIN vada ON vada.Id = srot_data.Vada   
          WHERE Linka = 'EXMET1'  
          GROUP BY vada  
          ORDER BY Total DESC limit 1";
   ```